# Expanding dimension of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm writing a finite difference toolkit, in my class I receive an array, that for sake of example will be defined as:

```
a=np.ones((5,4,3))
```

This is a spatial grid, I add one more dimension to give a time based evaluation, this time dimension for sake of simplicity will have 3 elements, for that I can do:

**1.**

```
b=np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
b=np.concatenate((b, np.zeros_like(b), np.zeros_like(b)), axis=0)
```

or, **2.**

```
c=np.tile(a, (3,) + (1,) * a.ndim)
c[1] = 0
c[2] = 0
```

or, **3.**

```
d=np.broadcast_to(a, (3, *a.shape)).copy()
d[1] = 0
d[2] = 0
```

All these approaches has some issues to me:

1. At least for me is ugly to use other values for timedimension, for example if I want 5 elements in time dimension i need to do something like `...(b, np_zeros_like(b), np_zeros_like(b), np_zeros_like(b), np_zeros_like(b))...`  that isn't elegant.
2. I have to build the tuple `(...)( 3, 1, 1, 1 )(...)`, from `a.ndim`, not elegant too.
3. Is the best one (imho). But I would like to know if i can expand with zeros, since from start without any need to explicitly setting it.

Any numpy methods (or anything else) to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of alternatives:

```
e = np.zeros((3,) + a.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
e[0] = a

f = np.einsum('i,...->i...', np.r_[1, np.zeros((3-1,))], a)

g = np.outer(0==np.arange(3), a).reshape((-1,) + a.shape)

h = np.where(0**np.array(range(3), ndmin=a.ndim+1).T, a, 0)
```

I myself would use the first one.

Comment: @Lin It's probably also one of the fastest, since it does almost nothing redundant. It allocates the target array. Everey method has to do that. It fills it with zeros. With the possible exception of the first plane every method has to do that, And it copies in the original array. Every method has to do that.